# Sub-millisecond timer in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

On Ubuntu, I am developing an application in C++ with Qt.
I'm using `QTimer` but it is not precise enough. I am looking for something with resolution better than a millisecond. Is there a way to do this?

my code :

```
temps= 0;
dataTimer = new QTimer();
connect(dataTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(simuler()));
dataTimer->start(1);
```

Comment: How about `usleep` in a worker thread? Or have a look at [POSIX timers](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html).

Comment: `QElapsedTimer` allows very high precision time, but not on Linux, unfortunately. There may be a third-party timer that will do what you need.

Comment: @JonHarper Give me an Example please

Comment: I don't code on Linux often, so I don't have a solution. Look into Karsten's ideas.

Comment: [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

Comment: Conciser that a lot of common hardware platforms do not have a realtime clock that runs at the accuracy you require.  It is possible on some platforms to re-program the hardware clock.

Comment: How do you think sub-millisecond would be meaningful on any system supporting Qt? I doubt it is ported to any real-time system, so you simply can't have that kind of accuracy.

Comment: **Why** exactly **do you ask?** Please *edit your question* to motivate it. What kind of application are you coding, and where do tiny delays come from and why do they matter?

Comment: Such timers are usually only useful when you're interacting with the outside world. It's pointless to ask for them if you don't tell us what the I/O mechanism is - it's likely that the selected mechanism introduces latencies that make sub-millisecond timing pointless. For example, full speed USB devices effectively operate on a 1ms clock and any new transactions will start after the next 1ms tick.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you won't *reliably* get sub-milliseconds delay for *useful actions* in practice (a Linux desktop is *not* a real-time system). Perhaps compiling your own kernel with `CONFIG_PREEMPT` might help a little! But this is a strong limitation (and there is no software tricks to overcome that).

As [Karsten Koop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3985859/karsten-koop) commented, you might use threads, or POSIX timers. See also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

As [Drop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1607442/drop) commented, if you compile in C++11 mode, consider using [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) (it is more or less wrapping `clock_gettime` in a C++11 conforming way; sou you'll be able to *measure* small delays).

A Linux specific solution might be to use [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) and poll that fd in the Qt main loop (using [QSocketNotifier](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsocketnotifier.html))

If you just want to *measure* (not *act*) time with sub-millisecond precision, just use [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)

Notice that several Qt operations are complex enough to need more than a millisecond to run. And human are not able to perceive (e.g. see on the screen) sub-millisecond delays. A screen is refreshed at 60Hz (or 144Hz for some *costly* screens), so you cannot see such small delays on it.

If you are not familiar with Linux programming, take time to read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) in *addition* of the hyperlinked material above (the [ALP](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) book is older than `timerfd_create`)

Comment: I will an exemple please , Exemple Hellow world with this !!

Comment: Don't have time to make the example: take several hours to read the material I have linked and experiment  by yourself.

Comment: My answer has several hyperlinks (in blue). Follow them.